# Expectation of a function of weighted sum of random variables: Is this coupling?

Tags: probability, expectation

Set of non negative weights $w_j$, set of non negative i.i.d. random variables $X_j$ and $f(y)$ is a decreasing nonnegative function in $y$.

I want to claim that:

if $\sum w_i<\sum w^{\prime}_i$,then $\mathbb E f(\sum w_iX_i)>\mathbb E f(\sum w^{\prime}_iX_i)$.

This seems intuitive but I would like a formal proof.

My attempt: The next line holds if all r.vs are coupled to a common r.v. $X_i\sim U$. But not sure if we can do that.
$$\sum w_iX_i< \sum w^{\prime}_iX_i,$$
We have  $$f(\sum w_iX_i)> f(\sum w^{\prime}_iX_i),$$ almost surely.

And we take expectation $$\mathbb E f(\sum w_iX_i)>\mathbb E f(\sum w^{\prime}_iX_i). \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (a)$$  Therefore the result holds a.s.

Is this proof correct? If wrong where is the mistake?

The function $f$ I have is $\log(1+\frac{1}{y})$ and $X_i$ are exponential r.vs.

Comment: What is $f$?  You use it without introducing it.

Comment: The inequality does not hold.

Comment: @nomen $f$ is any decreasing function. For example say $\frac{1}{x}$. Thanks

Comment: @Hansen Could you please clarify? thanks

Comment: Is $w_i$ nonnegative or allowed any value?

Comment: @Hansen weights and random variables are both non negative. Thanks.

Comment: You really have to carefully specify your conditions if you want to get a meaningful result.

Comment: @Hansen Sorry about that. The conditions are complete now. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_i w_iX_i < \sum_i w'_iX_i$?

Comment: @Tunococ Can't we replace all i.i.d. r.vs with a common r.v.? Then we can that your result

Comment: @triomphe No, you can't. Please see Hansen's answer.

Comment: "The next line holds if all r.vs are coupled to a common r.v. Xi∼U" What does "coupled to a common r.v." mean?

Comment: @Did Say we replace all $X_i$ by rv $U$ which has same distribution. Then a.s. $U\sum w_i<U\sum w^{\prime}$, I suppose? It is sufficient for me to know for exponential random variable and $f=log(\frac{1}{y})$. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be confusing "all $X_i$s are equal to $U$" (in which case the result is trivial) and "all $X_i$s have the same distribution" (a quite different hypothesis).

Comment: @Did So the $\sum w_i X_i<w_i^{\prime} X_i$ is wrong? Is there any valid assumption I can make for the claim to hold (other than the trivial case of equal to U)?

Comment: Yes, $\sum w_iX_i<\sum w'_iX_i$ is wrong. Consider $w=(0,1),w'=(2,0),X=(0,1)$.

Comment: @Hansen I understand if you fix $X$ that it is wrong. But in this case $X$ is random. Thanks

Comment: Of course I know $X$ is random. When $X$ is random, can you explain rigorously (1) why you think my counterexample does not apply? (2) what you mean by $\sum w'_iX_i-\sum w_iX_i$? If you think through carefully what exactly this expression you have written down means, you will understand why it is wrong.

Comment: Also, have you tried integrating $f$ with two exponential $X_i$'s? I believe you can get an analytic form. You should be able to see your claim does not hold.

Comment: @triomphe I can confirm that $\sum_i w_i X_i < w'_i X_i$ is wrong. Many have tried to point out to you but you don't seem willing to accept that your *intuition* is wrong. And no (again), you cannot replace all $X_i$ with one $U$. (If you throw two dice and add up the numbers, do you always get an even number?)

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is still wrong.

Consider decreasing function $f(y)=e^{-y},\ w=(1,1),\ w'=(2.5,0)$ and probability density $X\sim e^{-X}\mathbf 1_{X>0}$. One sees
$$E\big[f\big(\sum w_iX_i\big)\big]=\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{3.5}=E\big[f\big(\sum w'_iX_i\big)\big],$$
contrary to your claim.

Comment: The function is nonnegative. I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Your conclusion is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks. How about $\log (\frac{1}{y})$?

Comment: @triomphe If you want to specify that $f(y) = -\log y$, you should put it in your question. Anyway, even if it is this function, there will still be a counterexample. Your proof is wrong at the step that everyone (including yourself) doubts.

Answer (score 0):

When $X_i$ are i.i.d. standard normal distribution, as long as $\sum \omega_i^2 = \sum \omega_i'^2$, you get equality in expectation since $\sum \omega_i X_i$ and $\sum \omega_i'X_i$ have the same law.

Comment: Is my proof correct? Could you please elaborate? Why only hold for standard normal? thanks

Comment: It's a counterexample of your conclusion, so your proof has no chance to be correct...

Comment: My random variables are non negative. I edited the question. Thanks.