# Comparison of a functions with respect to two expectations

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose $X_i$ are i.i.d. nonnegative random variables and $w_i$ and $v_i$ are nonnegative weights.

It is given that $\mathbb E \sum w_i X_i < \mathbb E \sum v_iX_i$. Then can we claim that  $$\mathbb E \log(1+ \frac{1}{\sum v_iX_i})<\mathbb E \log(1+ \frac{1}{\sum w_iX_i}).$$

I tried with Jensen's inequality and could lover bound each side separately but couldn't establish the relationship I want.

I know that the expectations in $\mathbb E \sum w_i X_i < \mathbb E \sum v_iX_i$ cancels out as i.i.d. so $ \sum w_i  <  \sum v_i$. Which is equal to the condition in my previous question [Expectation of a function of weighted sum of random variables: Is this coupling?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884084/expectation-of-a-function-of-weighted-sum-of-random-variables-is-this-coupling) But hoping this condition is stronger to work on.

Comment: Did you try to check this new conjecture on the counterexample that was provided à propos your other question? You definitely should... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather laborious counterexample. There must be a simpler one...

Suppose $X_1,X_2 $ take values $1,2$ with probability ${1 \over 2}$.
Let $w_1=w_2 = 1$ and $v_1 =t, v_2 = 2$, with $t >0$. Then we have $3=E [\sum_i w_i X_i] < E [ \sum_i v_i X_i ]=3 + { 3 t \over 2}$.

We have
$E \log(1 + { 1 \over \sum_i w_i X_i}) = {1 \over 4} (\log {3 \over 2} + \log { 4 \over3} + \log { 4 \over3} + \log { 5 \over 4}  )$ and
$\epsilon_t = E \log(1 + { 1 \over \sum_i v_i X_i}) =
{1 \over 4} (\log(1+ {1 \over t+2}) + \log(1+ {1 \over t+4}) + \log(1+ {1 \over 2t+2}) + \log(1+ {1 \over 2t+4}))$.

Note that $e_0 = {1 \over 4} (\log {3 \over 2} + \log { 5 \over 4} + \log { 3 \over 2} + \log { 5 \over 4}  ) > E \log(1 + { 1 \over \sum_i w_i X_i})$, hence by continuity we have 
$E \log(1 + { 1 \over \sum_i w_i X_i}) < E \log(1 + { 1 \over \sum_i v_i X_i})$ for some small $t>0$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest a condition that would make the claim stand?

Comment: Other than $w_i \le v_i$, nothing leaps out at me.